# Why does JTextPane.setFont(null) sets monospaced font?

Tags: java, swing, jtextpane

I encountered a somewhat strange behaviour of Java Swing JTextPane. Why does `JTextPane.setFont(null)` sets monospaced font? It's totally illogical. I found it when I tried to debug `JTextPane.setFont(Font.getFont(Font.MONOSPACED))`, and it turned out that `Font.getFont` returns `null`.

Edit: when I `getFont()` after setting `null`, it returns `java.awt.Font[family=Lucida Grande,name=Lucida Grande,style=plain,size=13]`, and I dont't think that it is monospaced.

Comment: What do you expect should happen?  Setting a components font (especially a text component) to `null` seem illogical to me

Comment: I expected exception, but got desirable but strange behavior

Comment: Yeah, I might have expected a NPE, but it would seem the original authors didn’t want that an instead delegated the getFont to their parent containers getFont

Comment: getFont returns Lucida Grande but renders Monospaced. Hmm...

Comment: [mcve] please . .

Comment: So, having a look at the root element for the `StyledDocument` (when `JTextPane`'s font is `null`), it returns `javax.swing.plaf.FontUIResource[family=Monospaced,name=Monospaced,style=plain,size=12]`, so, based on observation, the `JTextPane` will override the `StyleDocument`'s default font if it's set

Comment: @MadProgrammer good track down - you might consider posting the comment as an answer :) While in hind-sight the styledDocument with its attributes should have looked obvious .. it wasn't my first thought ;)

Answer (score 0):

Calling `setFont` with `null` will set the component's `font` property to `null`.  The Swing designers obviously felt that this was a suitable solution and allowed `getFont` instead to return the parent container's `Font` (or `null` if the component didn't have a parent, in which case, it won't be painted, so it probably doesn't matter)

```
Font font = this.font;
if (font != null) {
    return font;
}
Container parent = this.parent;
return (parent != null) ? parent.getFont_NoClientCode() : null;
```

Just to be clear, on my system, doing the above will result in a `Font` of `null` until the frame is realised, after which it will return `com.apple.laf.AquaFonts$DerivedUIResourceFont[family=Lucida Grande,name=Lucida Grande,style=plain,size=13]`.  This is most likely coming from the Look and Feel.

In the case of the `JTextPane`, there's additional layer, the `StyledDocument`.

So, on my system, `UIManager.getFont("TextPane.font")` will return `com.apple.laf.AquaFonts$DerivedUIResourceFont[family=Lucida Grande,name=Lucida Grande,style=plain,size=13]`

```
StyledDocument doc = textPane.getDefaultRootElement().getAttributes();
System.out.println(doc.getFont(attributes));
```

Will print `javax.swing.plaf.FontUIResource[family=Monospaced,name=Monospaced,style=plain,size=12]` regardless of the `font` state of the `JTextPane`.

Sooo, observationally (as I'm not going to dig into the Look and Feel classes), if the `font` property is set on the `JTextPane`, it will override the `StyledDocument`'s root element's `Font` value (which, based on stepping through the code default's to `Monospaced` if no `Font` attribute exists)

Sooo, the answer is, it's complicated and may be different on different platforms based on the implementations/interactions of the Look and Feel.

Answer (score -1):

When you call setFont(null) on a JTextPane, it sets the font to the default font of the JTextPane's parent container. If the parent container does not have a default font set, then it will use a default font that is usually monospaced.

Comment: But I use default BorderLayout, why don't it has default font set?

Comment: Observationally, that might be correct, techncially, if the `font` is `null`, calling `getFont` will delegate to the parent containers `getFont` (or `null` if it doesn't have one) - I know, nit pick, but it sounds weird the way you've described it

Comment: BorderLayout does not have a default font set because it is just a layout manager and not a container itself.The default font of a container in Swing is determined by the look and feel. If the look and feel does not specify a default font, then the font of the parent container is used as the default font for its child components.

Comment: But after setting null font getFont returns Lucida Grande

Comment: n your case, since you are using a BorderLayout, the JTextPane is added to the center of the parent container, which is likely a JFrame. So when you call getFont() after setting the font to null, it returns the default font of the JFrame, which is "Lucida Grande".

Comment: JFrame contains a JRootPane, which contains a contentPane into which components are added, so, you’d be getting the contentPane’s font over the frames

Comment: actually, this answer is not quite correct (apart from the strange comment involving BorderLayout) a) specifically for _JTextPane_ it's the StyledDocument which chooses the default font (as @MadProgrammer commented to the question) b) for other swing components, the default font might be monospaced .. or not - in Swing it's decided by the LookAndFeel (metal and windows don't, didn't check the others)